# Connection to public WiFi drops after 2 minutes - Ubuntu 10.10/Realtek 8176

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I tried looking at similar questions, but I couldn't find an answer that offered any help for my situation.

When I connect to public WiFI that requires that I accept the TOS (Barnes and Nobles, Borders), my connection drops every minute or so and I have to reload the TOS page and sign in again.

I seem to still have the cookies stored... I don't know what else to check.

My wireless works fine otherwise. I can connect to public WiFi that doesn't require a sign in (hospital). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be they have a very short "idle" period.

You can try to run something like this in a terminal to keep the connection busy

```
while true ; do wget www.google.com 2> /dev/null; sleep 20; done
```

It connects to google every 20 seconds and throws away the data, type <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> to quit.

Comment: I'll give it a try. I didn't have problems in the past using my boss's Windows XP machine, but hopefully this will work.

Comment: This solution worked great.